# Sending cash by Polish post

Tags: money, switzerland, exchange, poland, mail

Recently I noticed that my 100 CHF cannot be exchanged since the Swiss National Bank assigned a rule. There was no way for me except sending by post. Does anybody have any experience. It is written in website that for Switzerland it is recommended not to send by post. However, the SNB itself accepts it this way.

What is the difference between Switzerland and other countries regarding sending cash? Please let me know if you had any experience?

**Update:** They received it no problem! This forum is conservative!

Comment: What is *snb*? Who are you sending cash to?

Comment: @Traveller [Swiss National Bank](https://www.snb.ch/en/)?

Comment: Yes :(..........

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a **bad idea** to send money by post, because it cannot be insured, so if it's stolen or disappears your money is gone.

However, it's usually not **illegal** to do so, so if you're willing to take the risk and trust the Polish post, the Swiss post and the Swiss National Bank, you can try your luck.

And in case you were wondering why OP can't just use a regular money changer: [Is this banknote still acceptable in Switzerland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163733/is-this-banknote-still-acceptable-in-switzerland/163755#163755)

Comment: Even if it is not illegal, it is at least in most West European countries a violation of the post operator's terms and conditions to send money in a plain letter. Swiss Post allows it for national letters, but *not* for international letters originating in Switzerland. Bank notes and coins are also listed as a prohibited item in the Universal Post Union's Convention, Article 19, 6.1 and are not allowed to be sent internationally in plain, uninsured letters. It may very well be, however, that the Polish Post allows money to be sent in registered and insured letters.

Comment: I dont think it is violation since snb itself told me to send it , btw I see your point.. At least for old banknote to snb or any other countries that assign a sudden rule it should be an exception. Since my goal is to change old one to a new one and I hope they receive it.

Comment: Yes I know it is a bad idea but no way:(

Comment: Btw why polish post writes that for Switzerland it is not recommended. It is just one of the few countries that they recommend not to send it. Strange!

Comment: @Turkan Switzerland is outside of the EU and the EU customs union so is subject to currency controls. Also Swiss bank accounts have long been used to shelter illegally obtained funds due to their banking secrecy regulations. Most countries do not like cash going to Switzerland (or at least used not to, don't know what they currently think, as things have changed a bit over the years).

Comment: @jcaron so you mean eu itself does not want not the switzerland. It is just 100 chf not more. I added a letter to it also explaining that it is an old bank note. It was sent by insured value letter. So what might be happened ?

Comment: @Turkan I mean that many EU member states don't like large amounts of cash going to Switzerland unchecked. The likeliest thing is probably that things will go through, it's not like they're opening each and very letter to see if there's cash inside. If for whatever reason someone decides to check, what will happen is anyone's guess. Possible options (in no particular order): they let it through, they return to sender, they keep the money, they fine you, they prosecute you (if there are laws or regulations which say it should be so). I feel the last two options are highly unlikely in your case.

Comment: Thank you. Oh my god because of 100 chf. I will inform what happened

Comment: It is in this stage I will let you know ! :
Customs clearance process underway
8010 Zürich Briefzentrum International